# Is a Power BI embedded visual in a web application usable when data is being refreshed?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

In the case of Power BI desktop, when I hit "Refresh", I get the following pop-up before all the visuals are re-rendered:
[image: Fig 1 - Refresh Data on Power BI Desktop]

Now consider a web page with a Power BI Embedded visual/dashboard. Something like this:
[image: Fig 2 - Sample Web Page with Power BI Embedded]

Assume that a user is interacting with this web page. Would the visual on the web page be usable (with old data) when a scheduled data refresh is in progress?, or will I get a similar pop-up (or loading screen) on the web page as shown in Fig 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been a while since I've used the PowerBI service, but as far as I remember, once you deploy your report in PowerBI Service it gets split into two different objects:

- Dataset (power query + the tabular model)
- Report (which is just the visualization part)

When a dataset is refreshing the reports built upon it keep working without any problem, and once the data load has been completed the reports/dashboards are refreshed (on active sessions the refresh had to be made manually though).

The embedded content should behave exactly as a PowerBI report, therefore and active session won't see any change, but a new one will see the new data. If needed you should be able to "force" the refresh even on active session using the API.

Comment: Assume that I have "forced" the refresh of the visual using the API. What would it look like? Is it going to reload the web page or just the visual?

Comment: It should reload only the visuals since you are using the PowerBi API (which interacts only with PowerBI visuals).

Comment: Got it. Thanks @Giovanni